What is the meaning of: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data) and how can be solved?
I'm trying to model a time series for a stock price with the following code:
import opendatasets as od
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf
import datetime

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

and I got the following structure:
                     date         close
0   2021-01-04 04:00:00-05:00   133.740000
1   2021-01-04 05:00:00-05:00   133.600000
2   2021-01-04 06:00:00-05:00   134.220000
3   2021-01-04 07:00:00-05:00   133.750000
4   2021-01-04 08:00:00-05:00   134.020000
... ... ...
4070    2021-12-30 13:30:00-05:00   178.975006
4071    2021-12-30 14:30:00-05:00   178.960007
4072    2021-12-30 15:30:00-05:00   178.250000
4073    2021-12-30 16:00:00-05:00   178.190000
4074    2021-12-30 17:00:00-05:00   177.980000

As a result I have
0    int64
dtype: object

However when I try to split the time series to train and test for an MLP model and fit it like this:
# splitting time series to train and test subsets
y_train = df.iloc[:-8766, :].copy()
y_test = df.iloc[-8766:, :].copy()

# Unobserved Components model definition
model = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(y_train,
                                    level='dtrend',
                                    irregular=True,
                                    stochastic_level = False,
                                    stochastic_trend = False,
                                    stochastic_freq_seasonal = [False, False, False],
                                    freq_seasonal=[{'period': 24, 'harmonics': 1},
                                                    {'period': 168, 'harmonics': 1},
                                                    {'period': 8766, 'harmonics': 2}])
# fitting model to train data
model_results = model.fit()

# printing statsmodels summary for model
print(model_results.summary())

I got the following error:
ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

I tried to convert the date column from string to date but with no success.
The np.asarray(df) returns the following
array([['2021-01-04 04:00:00-05:00', 133.740000]
       ['2021-01-04 05:00:00-05:00', 133.600000]
       ['2021-01-04 06:00:00-05:00', 134.220000]
       ...
       ['2021-31-12 17:00:00-05:00', 177.980000]], dtype = object)

I do not know if it is a problem with the date or close column and what to do to fix it.

if df['date'].dtype returns object, try df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) first

Same error ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data). Moreover, when I execute  df['date'].dtype I got dtype('O')

AFAIR, "date" needs to be the (date or time) index of the dataframe and not a regular column of the dataframe.

My understanding is that the dtype is heterogeneous (datetime or maybe even string for the first column and float for the second). Can you convert the datetime column to a float column (representing a duration in hours) instead?

If the issue still persists after using df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']), it is possible that there are some values in 'date' column which are not in 'datetime' dtype. You can identify those values by the following code:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', utc=True)

This will set those values to NaT(Not a Time). After this you can handle the missing values.
